# Oracle IDCS myApps Won't Display Application

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have tried to set the display in My Apps by clicking the checkbox and saving. The application type is confidential and was created using APEX.

Identity>Domains>TEST domain>Integrated applications>APP For User

Display settings
Display in My Apps(Checked)
Select if you want the application to be listed for users on their My Apps page.

I followed the directions in the following document.

OCI Identity Cloud Service (IDCS) - How To Display Apps In IDCS MyApps Page (Doc ID 2897542.1)

When I click user can request access, as a user I can request the app and then it is displayed in my apps.

How do I get the app to display without the user having to request it?

I am using self registration and MFA just in case that is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to modify group:
Identity>Domains>example domain>Groups

Click on all domains users

Click on Assign applications and select your application.

Now your application will appear in myconsole.